# Typescript generic optional param

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, prisma

I use [prisma](https://www.prisma.io/) to access my data in the DB want to create a class that will incapsulate database access logic (specifically I want to create Nest.js service).

Prisma does relatively sophisticated type checks to make sure that data access is type safe. Specifically it allows to specify which dependencies should be loaded.

Here is an example:

```js
// error here
const user1 = db.user.findOne({where: {id: '1'}});
console.log(user.groups); // compile time error

// this is valid
const user1 = db.user.findOne({where: {id: '1'}, include: {groups: true}});
console.log(user.groups); // all good
```

The problem is that I can't write a typesafe wrapper around prisma's findFirst function, so I can optionally include other relations.

Here is my current code:

```js
public async getUserById<TInclude extends Prisma.UserInclude>(
  id: string, 
  include?: TInclude
) {
  return db.user.findFirst({
    where: { id, /* another: criteria, */ },
    include: include,
  });
}
```

The problem is that this function always returns Promise<User & {} | null> and does not take into account includes. It happens because prisma constructs return type from `TInclude|undefined` even when I call my function with specific type:

```js
getUserById('1', {include: groups});
```

With this call Prisma constructs return type from `{include: groups} | undefined` even though in this specific call `include` is not undefined.

I can do something like:

```js
public async getUserById(id: string) {
  return this.getUserByIdWithInclude(id, {});
}

public async getUserByIdWithInclude<TInclude extends Prisma.UserInclude>(
  id: string, 
  include: TInclude // <--- not optional here
) {
  return db.user.findFirst({
    where: { id, /* another: criteria, */ },
    include: include,
  });
}
```

but this looks little bit less nice.

I also tried function overloads, but they require me to explicitly specify return time, which is not possible (Prisma's way to construct return type is sophisticated and I want to reuse, not replicate it).

Am I missing something that will allow me to write a nice typesafe wrapper?

Comment: If nobody with prisma knowledge comes along to help, you might consider removing the question's dependency on it by producing a self-contained typescript-only [mre].  If that does happen I'd be happy to come back and look (if notified).  Good luck!

Comment: You might be interested in [this thread](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/5273) which presents various solutions for building wrappers on Prisma. Your solution may be found there.

Comment: Have you tried using specifying [overload signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#overload-signatures-and-the-implementation-signature)?